# Conditional Field Background Color in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

i have this Conditional Field

```
=iif(Fields!ENTRADA.Value>Fields!Hora_IN.Value,"Yellow", "white")
```

But i wanna Add another condition:

i have another field: abrv

What i wanna do is:

```
Iff abrv.Value=F.C and (DATEDIFF( MI , @ENTRADA.Value , @Hora_IN.Value ) )>15 "Yellow", "white"

ELSE =iif(Fields!ENTRADA.Value>Fields!Hora_IN.Value,"Yellow", "white"),
```

Can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You actually still only have 2 potential outcomes, since two of those result in Yellow, so you can do this within one IIf statement:

```
=IIf(
    (Fields!abrv.Value = "F.C" and datediff(MI, Fields!ENTRADA.Value, Fields!Hora_IN.Value) > 15)
    or
    (Fields!ENTRADA.Value > Fields!Hora_IN.Value),
    "Yellow",
    "White"
)
```

Or, you can use Switch, since you are checking 3 different conditions.

```
=Switch(
    Fields!abrv.Value = "F.C" and datediff(MI, Fields!ENTRADA.Value, Fields!Hora_IN.Value) > 15, "Yellow",
    Fields!ENTRADA.Value > Fields!Hora_IN.Value, "Yellow",
    true, "White"
)
```

By putting "true" as the condition on the last line of the switch, that line basically acts as an "else", so anything that did not meet one of the conditions above it will get that value.